# Asesoria para generar una consulta

Tags: sql, sql-server

Solicito su apoyo para realizar la siguiente consulta, trabajo sobre SQL Server 2008 y se me presento la siguiente necesidad a la cual no he podido dar una certera respuesta.

El planteamiento es que el alumno tiene una columna en la cual se aloja el campo Plan = 16 por ej. el cual es una constante asignada desde el día que ingresa, y en otra tabla de materias a un plan le corresponden materias pero contemplando que siempre se debe mostrar la materia con el plan más nuevo siempre y cuando tenga una re-validación que se encuentra en el campo reva_plan dentro de la tabla materias por ej.

Materia = 1 Plan = 19 Reva_Plan = 16

Materia = 2 Plan = 16 Reva_Plan = 14

Materia = 2 Plan = 19 Reva_plan = 16

Materia = 3 Plan = 14 Reva_plan = 9

Materia = 3 Plan = 16 Reva_plan = 14

Materia = 3 Plan = 19 Reva_plan = 16

Dicho en una imagen sería así:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El campo buscado es Plan, que inicia en base al plan del Alumno y se busca entre la tabla materias y si tiene revalidación se obtiene el numero de plan más vigente.

He ideado algunas formas, pero no me han sido funcionales.

Muchas gracias por su tiempo, agradezco cualquier orientación...

Comment: Como lo veo parece que siempre se quiere la materia con el plan más alto. Has probado agrupando por materia y seleccionando MAX(Plan) ?

Comment: Saludos gracias por responder, lo he realizado así: select max(m.[plan]) as planestudio from materia m where m.CVE_MAT = '00937' group by rm.cve_mat 

Hasta ahora me ha resultado, cabe resaltar que lo tengo a la ves como sub-consulta en una consulta mas amplia, hasta ahora me ha sido funcional, ya he probado con 10 registros... gracias.

Comment: @MarcosBueno por favor use https://dbfiddle.uk/ para crear un [mcve]